# Trainer tire for Specialized mountain bike with a Cycle Ops

Tags: tire, trainer

I am looking for a trainer tire to use with my Cycle Ops and Specialized Hard Rock mountain bike that uses a 26 x 2.00 tube for outdoor. I have not been able to find this size in a trainer tire, what can I use? My regular tire is very loud when using with the Cycle Ops.

I appreciate help...

Kindest regards,  jeanie

Answer (score 2):

You can use a tire that is narrower than the regular one for use on a trainer. You can even use one that is nominally too narrow for the rim as the tire is not supporting any weight or resisting cornering forces. As along as the tire is not narrower than the outside of the rim it will work.

Also, if you can’t find a trainer specific tire you don't have to use one, any road tire with no tread or a light tread pattern will work.

Comment: Trainer tyres have the sole advantage of being harder. You can use a road tyre that has been discarded because of a cut on the rolling surface as long as you underlay the cut to prevent the tube from bulging.

Comment: “You can even use one that is nominally too small for the rim” I very much doubt you’d get it onto the rim.

Comment: @Michael I meant too narrow, edited answer